# Check and uncheck checkbox and read its state

Tags: jquery, checkbox, jquery-click-event

How can I read the state of my checkbox and set it's state to be visible ? I'm trying something like this, but it always returns true:

```
 $('.show-check').live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var checked = ($(this).is(':checked'));
    if(checked == true){
       $(this).attr('checked', true); 
    }
    else{
        $(this).attr('checked', false);
    }
 });


    <li>
        <img src="" class="show-image"/>
        <span class="show-title"></span>
        <input type="checkbox" class="show-check" />
    </li>
```

Comment: This looks like you're seeing if a checkbox is checked, and if it is, you're...checking it?

Comment: Um...what exactly are you trying to accomplish? Once the checkbox is checked, it has to stay checked forever?

Answer (score 1):

It works this way:

```
 $('.show-check').live('click', function() {


var checked = ($(this).is(':checked'));

if(checked){
   $(this).attr('checked', true);
}
else{
    $(this).attr('checked', false);
}
```

});

I think you couldn't check the checkbox because the default action is prevented, which is to check/uncheck the box

Here's my thought:

1. the checkbox is initially unchecked;
2. when you click the checkbox, the click event is fired, and the `var checked` is set to true;
3. since it's set to true, the `if(checked)` block will always be executed;
4. but you may wonder why the checkbox is not checked on the UI. I think it's because you set `e.preventDefault()` which tells the checkbox not to be affected by the default behaviour of click event, which is to check it;
5. the next time you check it again, same thing will happen.

Comment: do I have to reload parent container's html to see the result ? I'm still getting empty checkbox with 'true' value logged to console.

Comment: When did you check the value for the empty checkbox?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this would be clearer if you used the .change() event instead of the .clecked() event.

You are saying when the check box is clicked, if checked==true than set checked = true, so the false part will never be executed if you start with it checked.  The same is true if you start with it set to false.